# How can I make my button call a rotation of GIFs?

Tags: javascript, html, button, animated-gif

I have a button on a little page I built that reveals a DIV with a gif in it. Someone suggested it should call a new gif each time the button is clicked. I've hunted around for how to do this, but haven't been able to find a solution. 
How can I make it rotate through a selection of gif URLs each time the button is clicked again?

This is the code I currently have for the one gif:

HTML

`<button class="yes" type="button" onclick="revealDiv()">YES!</button>
    <div id="gifDIV">
    <iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/OSWRJKmwUEOD6" width="480" height="270" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/excited-dance-party-OSWRJKmwUEOD6"></a></p>
    </div>`

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
function revealDiv() {
document.getElementById('gifDIV').style.display = "block";
}
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I'm very new to this and this is the first time I've used JS so bear that in mind.
Thanks!

Comment: You can do this many ways. How/where do you want to store the list/collection of urls? Maybe an `array`?  I would also recommend you use the gif url if you want ti display this in a image tag `img` => `https://media.giphy.com/media/OSWRJKmwUEOD6/giphy.gif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create an array of links.

```
var ArrayGIF = ['https://media3.giphy.com/media/WNcbaCHN0mxsdJ2YXm/giphy.gif', 'https://media2.giphy.com/media/l3diOZVkXQ04BONB6/giphy.gif', 'https://media1.giphy.com/media/3o7bu0fTb50rSXgWsw/giphy.gif', 'https://media0.giphy.com/media/XKJ52vGno1REavaO5j/giphy.gif'];
```

Everytime the button gets clicked, you generate a random number, that is between zero and the length of your array.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * ArrayGIF.length);
```

Finally you set the img src:

```
document.getElementById('gif').src = ArrayGIF[randomNumber];
```

Here is the final result:
https://jsfiddle.net/kq0o2Lyc/12/

I changed your code a litte bit, its no longer using a iframe to display the gif.

Answer (score 1):

You can store an array of GIF URLs, and then cycle through them each time. You do this by changing the `src` of the `iframe`.

https://jsfiddle.net/iONinja/p1w406yn/7/

```
<script>
var gifs = ["https://giphy.com/embed/8vQSQ3cNXuDGo", "https://giphy.com/embed/JIX9t2j0ZTN9S", "https://giphy.com/embed/vFKqnCdLPNOKc"];
var n = 0;

function revealDiv() {
    document.getElementById("gifDIV").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("gifIFRAME").src = gifs[n];
    n++;
    if (n >= gifs.length) {
        n = 0;
    }
}
</script>

<button class="yes" type="button" onclick="revealDiv()">YES!</button>
<div id="gifDIV"><iframe id="gifIFRAME" src="" width="480" height="480" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
```